# How to send multiple objects to nested child component in one input using Angular 6

Tags: angular, nested, components

I would like to send multiple objects or parameters to child component using one input :

```
<child [OneInput]="{object1,object2}"></child>
```

Because in child component im usnig set method to get data from parent component

```
@Input()
set OneInput(data)
{
 console.log(data)
}
```

i don't want to create a separated variable kind `let obj= {obj1:data1,obj2:data2}`

Any help please.

Comment: Create object on the `.ts` `let object = {object1,object2}` and then used that variable on view as `<child [OneInput]="object"></child>`

Comment: is there any possibility to do it without touching ts file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on your component, you specify 2 variables that you want to pass in your template then you can directly pass it on [OneInput]

**ParentComponent**

```
@Component({
   ...,
   template: `<child [OneInput]="{userList: users, positionList: positions}"></child>`
})
export class ParentComponent {

   users = ['user1', 'user2'];
   positions = ['position1', 'position2'];

}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
@Component({...})
export class ChildComponent {

   @Input()
   set OneInput({userList, positionList}) {    // You can use data or you can destructure it to directly access the objects without having to data.userList and data.positionList
      console.log(userList, positionList)
   }

}
```